# Предварительная загрузка данных перед началом работы приложения

Tags: java, mysql, spring

Работаю над проектом (страничка шиномонтажа), перед началом работы приложения мне нужно загрузить данные в БД, а именно - прайс листы. Каким образом я могу это сделать? То есть, что бы прайсы загрузились и остались навсегда? Использую `Spring` с xml-конфигурациями и аннотациями.

Comment: Проще всего загрузить через любую утилиту работы с СУБД используя sql-файлы.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону batch (https://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-example-csv-file-to-database/).

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать `liquibase` - opensource проект для версионного измения бд. С его помощью возможно сделать проверку при старте приложения на наличие определенных данных. Если проверка не прошла то выполнить скрипт: `sql` или `xml changelogs`.  Присутствует [интеграция со spring](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/spring.html)

Хотя, возможно, проще все же самому это запрограммировать.

Answer (score 0):

Я не использую XML конфигурацию в Spring. Но постараюсь помочь. У вас есть бин (класс), который конфигурирует работу с вашей БД. В XML конфигурации бина есть такая штука как init-method="someCustomMethod". someCustomMethod - это метод в вашем классе бина, который вызывается после полной инициализации вашего бина. И в этом методе вы уже можете обращаться в базу и проводить с ней манипуляции. Это будет происходить при каждом деплое вашего приложения.
Вот пример [использования этого подхода](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-init-method-and-destroy-method-example/).